# Boost Asio async_read and async_receive not getting called itself whenever there is a data on tcp socket But boost::asio::read got call automatically

Tags: c++, linux, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am making a bidirectional asynchronous (non blocking) TCP client/server
socket communication in Linux where a server can handle multiple clients. I am
using boost ASIO TCP library framework for my requirements.

In my project there are two processes: client and server.

I want to transfer a custom structure (which has some enums, strings
and other kind of data) over the TCP. For that I use Boost Serialization.

In both server and client I have implemented `startReading()` and
`startWriting()` function in async mode using `async_read` and `async_write`.

To test, I

- start server process, like

  ```
   ./test_server 9876
  ```
- whenever a client process start from command line like

  ```
   ./test_client 127.0.0.1 9876
  ```

  Instantly, it will connect we see the server
  notification that a client is connected.
- Now client sends a hello message to the server. The server immediately
  replies with serialized struct.

The client is not getting the reply, whether I use `async_read` or `async_receive`.

If I am using a blocking `asio::read` in the client `startReading()`, the
client gets the message.

But I want it async.

I am sharing the completed project code below, please check and give me some
suggestions. I am using ubuntu 20.04 64 bit os, C++14, Boost 1.71.

Server Logs
[image: "Server Logs"]

Client Read Logs (which is working)
[image: "Clients Read Logs"]

Client async_read logs which is not working
[image: "Client async read logs"]

**test_server.cpp 'its server process main function'**

```
//test_server.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "tcpServer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Missing port no: Please pass port no argument in async_tcp_server\n";
      return 1;
    }
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    TcpServer server(io_context,std::atoi(argv[1]));
    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception &e)
  {
    std::cerr <<"Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**This is tcpServer.h**

```
//tcpServer.h
#ifndef TCP_SERVER_H
#define TCP_SERVER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <string>
#include "AppPlugin.h"


/**
*   @class  TcpConnectionHandler tcpServer.h "server/tcpServer.h"
*   @brief  
*/
class TcpConnectionHandler : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnectionHandler>
{
private:
    tcp::socket serverSocket_;
    TcpConnectionHandler(boost::asio::io_context&);
    TestManagerComInfo messageInfo;

public:
    enum { max_length = 4096};
    char data[max_length];
    string message="ok client, I am sending the strucure!";
    
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<TcpConnectionHandler> pointer;
    // creating the pointer
    static inline pointer create(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
    {
        return pointer(new TcpConnectionHandler(io_context));
    }
    //socket creation
    tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return serverSocket_;
    }

    void StartReading();
    void StartWriting();
    void WriteDone(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t);
    void ReadDone(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t);
    void setMessageStruct(const TestManagerComInfo&);
    TestManagerComInfo& getMessageStruct()
    {
        return messageInfo;
    }
    void SockDiscNotifierServer();
};

/**
*   @class  TcpServer tcpServer.h "server/tcpServer.h"
*   @brief  
*/
class TcpServer 
{
private:
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context_local;
    boost::asio::io_context& getioContext()
    {
        return io_context_local;
    }
   void start_accept();

public:
    TcpServer(boost::asio::io_context&,short);  
};

#endif  // TCP_SERVER_H
```

**This is tcpserver.cpp**

```
//tcpServer.cpp
#include "tcpServer.h"


TcpConnectionHandler::TcpConnectionHandler(boost::asio::io_context &io_context) : serverSocket_(io_context)
{
messageInfo.requestType_ = kTerminate;
    messageInfo.name_ = "COM_IPC_GROUP_001";
    messageInfo.testLogType_ = {
        {"Test1", kTestPass},
        {"Test112", kTestFail},
        {"Test3", kTestAbort}
    };
    messageInfo.statusType_ = kCompleted;
}

void TcpConnectionHandler::setMessageStruct(const TestManagerComInfo &passedMessageStruct)
{
#if 0
    messageInfo.requestType_ = kTerminate;
    messageInfo.name_ = "COM_IPC_GROUP_001";
    messageInfo.testLogType_ = {
        {"Test1", kTestPass},
        {"Test2", kTestFail},
        {"Test3", kTestAbort}
    };
    messageInfo.statusType_ = kCompleted;
#endif

    messageInfo.requestType_ = passedMessageStruct.requestType_;
    messageInfo.name_ = passedMessageStruct.name_;
    for (const auto &entry : passedMessageStruct.testLogType_)
    {
        messageInfo.testLogType_[entry.first] = entry.second;
    }
    messageInfo.statusType_ = passedMessageStruct.statusType_;
}

void TcpConnectionHandler::StartReading()
{
    serverSocket_.async_read_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(data, max_length),
        boost::bind(&TcpConnectionHandler::ReadDone,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));    
}

void TcpConnectionHandler::StartWriting()
{
    string serializedData = serializeMessageStruct(getMessageStruct());
        serverSocket_.async_write_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(serializedData, max_length),
        boost::bind(&TcpConnectionHandler::WriteDone,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
void TcpConnectionHandler::ReadDone(const boost::system::error_code &err, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        cout << "server received data is '" << data << "'\n";
        StartWriting();
    }
    else
    {
        SockDiscNotifierServer();
        cerr << "Read error: " << err.message() << endl;
    }
}

void TcpConnectionHandler::WriteDone(const boost::system::error_code &err, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        cout << "Server sent message!" << endl;
        serverSocket_.is_open()?cout<<"Server socket is still connected\n":cout<<"server socket got disconnected\n";
    }
    else
    {
        SockDiscNotifierServer();
        cerr << "Write error: " << err.message() << endl;
    }
}

void TcpConnectionHandler::SockDiscNotifierServer()
{
    cout<<"server notifier handler for socket disconnect\n";
}

/********************************************************************************************************************************************************************/

TcpServer::TcpServer(boost::asio::io_context &io_context, short port_No) : io_context_local(io_context), acceptor_(io_context,
                                                                                                                   tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port_No))
{
    start_accept();
}

void TcpServer::start_accept()
{
    TcpConnectionHandler::pointer connection = TcpConnectionHandler::create(getioContext());
        acceptor_.async_accept(connection->socket(), [this,connection](boost::system::error_code ec) {
        std::cout << "async_accept -> " << ec.message() << "\n";
        if (!ec) {
            connection->StartReading();
            start_accept();
        }
    });
}
```

**test_client.cpp 'its client process main function'**

```
//test_client.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "tcpClient.h"

// Client side
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // we need 2 things: ip address and port number, in that order
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: ip_address port" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    char *serverIp = argv[1];
    char *port = argv[2];
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    TcpClient tcpcli(io_context,serverIp, port);
     std::thread io_thread([&io_context]() {
        io_context.run();
    });
    tcpcli.StartWriting();
    sleep(1);
    tcpcli.StartReading();
    io_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

**This is tcpClient.h**

```
//tcpClient.h
#ifndef TCP_CLIENT_H
#define TCP_CLIENT_H

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "AppPlugin.h"



/**
 *   @class  TcpClient tcpClient.h "client/tcpClient.h"
 *   @brief
 */
class TcpClient
{
public:
    TcpClient(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, string serverIp, string port);
    void readData(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t);
    void sendData(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t);
    enum
    {
        max_length = 4096
    };
    void SockDiscNotifierClient();
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socketClient_;
    void StartReading();
    void StartWriting();

private:
    string serverIp_, port_;
    bool connectStatus;
    boost::asio::streambuf recvBuffer_;
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context_local;
    boost::asio::io_context& getioContext()
    {
        return io_context_local;
    }
    //TestManagerComInfo DeserializeMessageStruct(boost::asio::streambuf&);

};

#endif  // TCP_CLIENT_H
```

**This is tcpClient.cpp**
In this code I have implemented 3 startReading() and startWriting() functions. The first is implemented by me and working second I have reffered from google and boost documentation 3rd I have taken reference from chatgpt.

```
//tcpClient.cpp
#include "tcpClient.h"

TcpClient::TcpClient(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, string serverIp, string port)
    : serverIp_(serverIp), port_(port), socketClient_(io_context), io_context_local(io_context)
{
    connectStatus = false;
    if(!connectStatus)
    {
        socketClient_.connect(tcp::endpoint(
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(serverIp_), std::stoi(port_)));
        connectStatus = true;
    }
    std::cout << "Client Started: \n"; 
}

//This StartReading is working
#if 1 //first startreading
void TcpClient::StartReading()
{
    // getting response from server
    cout<<"----->TcpClient::StartReading\n";
    boost::system::error_code error;
    //boost::asio::streambuf receiveBuff;
    boost::asio::read(socketClient_, recvBuffer_, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);
    if (error && error != boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
        SockDiscNotifierClient();
        cout << "receive failed: " << error.message() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        DeserializeMessageStruct(recvBuffer_);        
    }
}
#endif

//This StartReading is not working
#if 0 //second startreading
void TcpClient::StartReading()
{
    cout << "----->TCPClient::StartReading\n";
    boost::asio::async_read(socketClient_, recvBuffer_, boost::asio::transfer_all(),
                            [this](const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
                            {
                                cout<<"in TCPClient::StartReading labda\n";
                               // getioContext().run();
                                if (!error)
                                {
                                    std::string receivedData(boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(recvBuffer_.data()), boost::asio::buffer_size(recvBuffer_.data()));
                                    cout<<"deserializing client received\n"<<receivedData;
                                    recvBuffer_.consume(bytes_transferred);
                                    StartReading();
                                    //DeserializeMessageStruct(recvBuffer_);
                                }
                                else if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
                                {
                                    std::cerr << "Server closed the connection." << std::endl;
                                    socketClient_.close(); // Close the socket
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    std::cerr << "Client: Error reading data: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                                }
                            });
                            
}
#endif

//This is suggested by chatgpt and its also not working
#if 0 //third startreading
void TcpClient::StartReading() {
    // Create a lambda function that encapsulates the StartReading logic
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context = static_cast<boost::asio::io_context&>(socketClient_.get_executor().context());
    auto readOperation = [this,&io_context]() {
        cout << "----->TCPClient::StartReading\n";
        socketClient_.async_receive(
        boost::asio::buffer(recvBuffer_.prepare(max_length)),
        [this](const boost::system::error_code &err, size_t bytes_transferred)
        {
            if (!err)
            {
                //recvBuffer_.commit(bytes_transferred); // Commit the received data
                DeserializeMessageStruct(recvBuffer_);
            }
            else
            {
                SockDiscNotifierClient();
                cerr << "Read error: " << err.message() << endl;
            }
        });
        io_context.run();
    };
    std::thread readingThread(readOperation);

    readingThread.join();
}
#endif


#if 1 //First StartWriting
void TcpClient::StartWriting()
{
     // request/message from client
    const string msg = "Hello Server Please send me the strucure!\n";
    cout<<"----->TcpClient::StartWritin\n";

    socketClient_.async_write_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(msg, max_length),
        boost::bind(&TcpClient::sendData, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

}
#endif

#if 0 //Second StartWriting
void TcpClient::StartWriting()
{
    // Request/message from client
    const string msg = "Hello Server Please send me the structure!\n";
    cout << "----->TcpClient::StartWriting\n";

    // Start an asynchronous write operation
    socketClient_.async_write_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(msg, max_length),
        [this](const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                cout << "Client Successfully Sent Message!\n";
                // Start reading after writing is complete
                StartReading();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "Send error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            }
        });
}
#endif 

#if 0 //Third StartWriting
void TcpClient::StartWriting() {
    // Request/message from client
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context = static_cast<boost::asio::io_context&>(socketClient_.get_executor().context());  
    const string msg = "Hello Server Please send me the structure!\n";
    cout << "----->TcpClient::StartWriting\n";
    // Create a lambda function that encapsulates the StartWriting logic
    auto writeOperation = [this, &io_context, msg]() {
        socketClient_.async_write_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(msg, max_length),
            [this](const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                if (!error) {
                    cout << "Client Successfully Sent Message!\n";
                    // Start reading after writing is complete
                     StartReading();
                } else {
                    std::cerr << "Send error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                }
            });
            io_context.run();
    };

    // Create a thread and execute the lambda function
    std::thread writingThread(writeOperation);
   // Wait for the thread to finish
    writingThread.join();
}
#endif

void TcpClient::readData(const boost::system::error_code &err,
                         size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        cout << "Client Successfuly Read Message! ";
    }
    else
    {
        SockDiscNotifierClient();
        cerr << "Read error: " << err.message() << endl;
    }
}

void TcpClient::sendData(const boost::system::error_code &err,
                         size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        cout << "Client Successfuly Sent Message!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        SockDiscNotifierClient();
        cerr << "Send error: " << err.message() << endl;
    }
}

void TcpClient::SockDiscNotifierClient()
{
    cout<<"client notifier handler for socket disconnect";
    
}
```

**This is AppPlugin.h, which contains serialize and deserialize function also the defination of structure**

```
//AppPlugin.h
#ifndef APPPLUGIN_H
#define APPPLUGIN_H

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using std::cerr;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

enum RequestType
{
    kSatelliteStatus = 0x00,
    kApplicationPresence = 0x01,
    kExecuteTestSuite = 0x02,
    kTestSuiteLog = 0x03,
    kTerminate = 0x04
};

enum StatusType
{
    kInit = 0x00,
    kStarted = 0x01,
    kCompleted = 0x02
};

enum TestResultType
{
    kTestNotExecute,
    kTestPass,
    kTestFail,
    kTestAbort
};

using TestLogType = std::map<std::string, TestResultType>;

#pragma pack(push, 1)  // Pack the structure
struct TestManagerComInfo
{
    RequestType requestType_;
    std::string name_;
    TestLogType testLogType_;
    StatusType statusType_;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar& requestType_;
        ar& name_;
        ar& testLogType_;
        ar& statusType_;
    }
};
#pragma pack(pop)  // Restore default packing

/**
* @fn serializeMessageStruct
* @brief Its for serialize the TestManagerComInfo struct and convert into the string
* @param messageInfoNeedtoSerialize is the argunment which is TestManagerComInfo's object
*/
inline string serializeMessageStruct(TestManagerComInfo &messageInfoNeedtoSerialize)
{
    std::ostringstream archiveStream;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archiveStream);
    archive << messageInfoNeedtoSerialize;
    return archiveStream.str();
}

inline TestManagerComInfo DeserializeMessageStruct(boost::asio::streambuf& deserializeBuff)
{
    TestManagerComInfo receivedMsgStruct;
    std::istream archiveStream(&deserializeBuff);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archiveStream);
        archive >> receivedMsgStruct;
        cout << "Received Request Type: "
             << static_cast<int>(receivedMsgStruct.requestType_) << std::endl;
        cout << "Received Name: " << receivedMsgStruct.name_ << std::endl;
        cout << "Received Test Log:" << endl;
        for (const auto &test : receivedMsgStruct.testLogType_)
        {
            cout << "  " << test.first << ": " << test.second << endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Received Status Type: "
                  << static_cast<int>(receivedMsgStruct.statusType_)
                  << std::endl;

    return receivedMsgStruct;
}



#endif  // APPPLUGIN_H
```

Answer (score 0):

A first question that rises is: why do you want to make the operation async.

A second question is: what implementation do you **wish** to land on. I'm going to assume implementation 2 - the one that you hand-wrote.

Regardless of everything, the problem is the same:

```
TcpClient   tcpcli(io_context, serverIp, port);
std::thread io_thread([&io_context]() { io_context.run(); });

tcpcli.StartWriting();
sleep(1);
```

The `io_thread` runs out of work. Whether it does so before `StartWriting()` is invoked is a race condition - it will depend on the weather conditions. However, the `sleep(1)` simply *guarantees* that `io_thread` is done¹.

You need a work guard of sorts to prevent the thread from exiting prematurely. My favorite approach is to use `asio::thread_pool` which does this internally:

```
boost::asio::thread_pool io_context(1); // single thread

TcpClient tcpcli(io_context.get_executor(), serverIp, port);

tcpcli.StartWriting();
io_context.join();
```

This requires you to modify your code to accept executors instead of hard-coding `io_context&`.

### Why Is The Server Okay?

Glad you asked. The `TcpServer` is different, because it kicks of an infinite chain of async operations from inside its constructor, so there is always work:

```
TcpServer::TcpServer(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, std::uint16_t port_No)
    : io_context_local(io_context)
    , acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port_No)) {
    start_accept();
}
```

## Code Review

Your code has some issues.

1. There's a lot of code that doesn't belong in header files.
2. Similarly there's a lot of excess member visibility.
3. The use of `io_context&` references throughout is unnecessarily limiting.
4. - `DeserializeMessageStruct` not only doesn't belong in the header,
   - it shouldn't depend on Asio either
   - I would split the printing code out as well.
   - On serialization, make sure the archive is complete before extracting the string.

```
So we get `AppPlugin.cpp`:

    #include "AppPlugin.h"
    #include <ostream>
    #include <sstream>
    
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, TestManagerComInfo const& msg) {
        os << "Request Type: " << static_cast<int>(msg.requestType_) << std::endl;
        os << "Name: " << msg.name_ << std::endl;
        os << "Test Log:" << std::endl;
        for (auto const& [k, v] : msg.testLogType_) {
            os << "  " << k << ": " << v << std::endl;
        }
        os << "Status Type: " << static_cast<int>(msg.statusType_) << std::endl;
        return os;
    }
    
    std::string serializeMessageStruct(TestManagerComInfo& msg) {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(oss);
            archive << msg;
        } // SEHE: completes the archive
        return oss.str();
    }
    
    TestManagerComInfo DeserializeMessageStruct(std::streambuf& deserializeBuff) {
        TestManagerComInfo msg;
        std::istream archiveStream(&deserializeBuff);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive(archiveStream) >> msg;
        return msg;
    }

And then on usage, you write:

    TestManagerComInfo msg = DeserializeMessageStruct(recvBuffer_);
    std::cout << "RECEIVED: " << msg;
```

5. You clearly didn't enable compiler warnings, or you would notice the type mismatches on ports and e.g. wrong member initialization orders, unused variables etc.
6. Note that `#pragma pack` has no effect if you're serializing using Boost
   Serialization as you do. In fact, it's unportable by definition and can
   only be a performance pessimization as your struct isn't trivial,
   standard-layout or POD anyways.
7. The dance with buffers is very inefficient:

   ```
   std::string receivedData(asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(recvBuffer_.data()),
                            asio::buffer_size(recvBuffer_.data()));
   std::cout << "deserializing client received\n" << receivedData;
   TestManagerComInfo msg = DeserializeMessageStruct(recvBuffer_);
   recvBuffer_.consume(bytes_transferred);
   ```

   This could "just" be

   ```
   std::cout << "RECEIVED: " << DeserializeMessageStruct(recvBuffer_);
   ```
8. You also redundantly invoke `StartReading` from main, where it already happens from the completion handler in `StartWriting`.
9. The message "Server socket is still connected" is misleading, as `is_open` doesn't imply that the peer hasn't shutdown the connection.
10. `tranfer_all()` is the default completion condition for `async_read`.
11. Your `async_write_some` needs to be `asio::async_write` to ensure the full buffer gets sent. You are passing a local variable as the buffer, which is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because it doesn't live till completion of the async operation. Either make it static or e.g. a member variable.
12. Applying the unrelated `max_length` to it is ... useless at best.
13. `SockDiscNotifierClient` is misleading, as it's not always called in response to disconnection. That said, `sendData`/`readData` seem unnecessary now, so I'll just remove them.
14. There's a bunch of inconsistent `using namespace` and `std::endl` vs `'\n'` (use `std::endl` if you expect a flush).

Hmm. Now I'm noticing the server also uses `async_read_some` and `async_write_some` instead of composed operations that avoid partial messages. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader for now.

> PS: later I changed the interface to take an `istream` instead of `streambuf`

¹ (unless somehow writing took longer than a second, which seems improbable)

### PUTTING IT ALL TOGETHER

- File `tcpServer.h`

  ```
   // tcpServer.h
   #ifndef TCP_SERVER_H
   #define TCP_SERVER_H

   #include "AppPlugin.h"
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <string>

   /**
    *   @class  TcpServer tcpServer.h "server/tcpServer.h"
    *   @brief
    */
   class TcpServer {
     private:
       boost::asio::any_io_executor   io_context_local;
       boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
       boost::asio::any_io_executor   getioContext() { return io_context_local; }
       void                           start_accept();

     public:
       TcpServer(boost::asio::any_io_executor, uint16_t);
   };

   #endif // TCP_SERVER_H
  ```
- File `tcpServer.cpp`

  ```
   // tcpServer.cpp
   #include "tcpServer.h"
   #include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <memory>

   namespace asio = boost::asio;
   using asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;

   /**
    *   @class  TcpConnectionHandler tcpServer.h "server/tcpServer.h"
    *   @brief
    */
   class TcpConnectionHandler : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnectionHandler> {
     private:
       tcp::socket serverSocket_;
       TcpConnectionHandler(asio::any_io_executor);
       TestManagerComInfo messageInfo;

       enum { max_length = 4096 };
       char        data[max_length];
       std::string message = "ok client, I am sending the structure!";

     public:
       using pointer = std::shared_ptr<TcpConnectionHandler>;
       // creating the pointer
       static inline pointer create(asio::any_io_executor io_context) {
           return pointer(new TcpConnectionHandler(io_context));
       }
       // socket creation
       tcp::socket& socket() { return serverSocket_; }

       void StartReading();
       void StartWriting();
       void WriteDone(error_code, size_t);
       void ReadDone(error_code, size_t);
       void setMessageStruct(TestManagerComInfo const&);
       void SockDiscNotifierServer();

       TestManagerComInfo const& getMessageStruct() const { return messageInfo; }
       TestManagerComInfo&       getMessageStruct() { return messageInfo; }
   };

   TcpConnectionHandler::TcpConnectionHandler(asio::any_io_executor io_context) : serverSocket_(io_context) {
       messageInfo.requestType_ = kTerminate;
       messageInfo.name_        = "COM_IPC_GROUP_001";
       messageInfo.testLogType_ = {{"Test1", kTestPass}, {"Test112", kTestFail}, {"Test3", kTestAbort}};
       messageInfo.statusType_  = kCompleted;
   }

   void TcpConnectionHandler::setMessageStruct(TestManagerComInfo const& passedMessageStruct) {
   #if 0
       messageInfo.requestType_ = kTerminate;
       messageInfo.name_ = "COM_IPC_GROUP_001";
       messageInfo.testLogType_ = {
           {"Test1", kTestPass},
           {"Test2", kTestFail},
           {"Test3", kTestAbort}
       };
       messageInfo.statusType_ = kCompleted;
   #endif

       messageInfo.requestType_ = passedMessageStruct.requestType_;
       messageInfo.name_        = passedMessageStruct.name_;
       for (auto const& entry : passedMessageStruct.testLogType_) {
           messageInfo.testLogType_[entry.first] = entry.second;
       }
       messageInfo.statusType_ = passedMessageStruct.statusType_;
   }

   void TcpConnectionHandler::StartReading() {
       serverSocket_.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data, max_length),
                                     boost::bind(&TcpConnectionHandler::ReadDone, shared_from_this(),
                                                 asio::placeholders::error,
                                                 asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
   }

   void TcpConnectionHandler::StartWriting() {
       std::string serializedData = serializeMessageStruct(getMessageStruct());
       serverSocket_.async_write_some(asio::buffer(serializedData, max_length),
                                      boost::bind(&TcpConnectionHandler::WriteDone, shared_from_this(),
                                                  asio::placeholders::error,
                                                  asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
   }

   void TcpConnectionHandler::ReadDone(error_code err, size_t bytes_transferred) {
       if (!err) {
           std::cout << "server received data is "
                     << std::quoted(std::string_view(data, bytes_transferred), '\'') << std::endl;
           StartWriting();
       } else {
           SockDiscNotifierServer();
           std::cerr << "Read error: " << err.message() << std::endl;
       }
   }

   void TcpConnectionHandler::WriteDone(error_code err, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
       if (!err) {
           std::cout << "Server sent message!" << std::endl;
       } else {
           SockDiscNotifierServer();
           std::cerr << "Write error: " << err.message() << std::endl;
       }
   }

   void TcpConnectionHandler::SockDiscNotifierServer() {
       std::cout << "server notifier handler for socket disconnect" << std::endl;
   }

   /********************************************************************************************************************************************************************/

   TcpServer::TcpServer(asio::any_io_executor io_context, uint16_t port)
       : io_context_local(io_context)
       , acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)) {
       start_accept();
   }

   void TcpServer::start_accept() {
       TcpConnectionHandler::pointer connection = TcpConnectionHandler::create(getioContext());
       acceptor_.async_accept(connection->socket(), [this, connection](error_code ec) {
           std::cout << "async_accept -> " << ec.message() << std::endl;
           if (!ec) {
               connection->StartReading();
               start_accept();
           }
       });
   }
  ```
- File `tcpClient.h`

  ```
   // tcpClient.h
   #ifndef TCP_CLIENT_H
   #define TCP_CLIENT_H

   #include <boost/asio.hpp>

   /**
    *   @class  TcpClient tcpClient.h "client/tcpClient.h"
    *   @brief
    */
   class TcpClient {
     public:
       TcpClient(boost::asio::any_io_executor io_context, std::string serverIp, std::string port);
       void StartWriting();

     private:
       void StartReading();

       boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socketClient_;
       std::string                  serverIp_, port_;
       bool                         connectStatus;
       boost::asio::streambuf       recvBuffer_;
   };

   #endif // TCP_CLIENT_H
  ```
- File `tcpClient.cpp`

  ```
   // tcpClient.cpp
   #include "tcpClient.h"
   #include "AppPlugin.h"
   #include <iostream>

   namespace asio = boost::asio;
   using asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;

   TcpClient::TcpClient(asio::any_io_executor ex, std::string serverIp, std::string port)
       : socketClient_(ex)
       , serverIp_(serverIp)
       , port_(port) //
   {
       connectStatus = false;
       if (!connectStatus) {
           socketClient_.connect(tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::address::from_string(serverIp_),
                                               static_cast<uint16_t>(std::stoi(port_))));
           connectStatus = true;
       }
       std::cout << "Client Started: \n";
   }

   static const std::string s_msg = "Hello Server Please send me the structure!\n";

   void TcpClient::StartReading() {
       std::cout << "----->TCPClient::StartReading\n";
       asio::async_read( //
           socketClient_, recvBuffer_, [this](error_code error, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
               std::cout << "in TCPClient::StartReading completion handler (" << error.message() << ")\n";
               if (!error || error == asio::error::eof) {
                   std::cout << "RECEIVED: " << DeserializeMessageStruct(recvBuffer_) << "--------\n";
               }
           });
   }

   void TcpClient::StartWriting() {
       // Request/message from client
       std::cout << "----->TcpClient::StartWriting\n";

       // Start an asynchronous write operation
       socketClient_.async_write_some( //
           asio::buffer(s_msg), [this](error_code error, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
               if (!error) {
                   std::cout << "Client Successfully Sent Message!\n";
                   // Start reading after writing is complete
                   StartReading();
               } else {
                   std::cerr << "Send error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
               }
           });
   }
  ```
- File `test_server.cpp`

  ```
   // test_server.cpp
   #include "tcpServer.h"
   #include <iostream>

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) try {
       if (argc != 2) {
           std::cerr << "Missing port no: Please pass port no argument in async_tcp_server\n";
           return 1;
       }
       boost::asio::io_context io_context;
       TcpServer server(io_context.get_executor(), static_cast<uint16_t>(std::atoi(argv[1])));
       io_context.run();
   } catch (std::exception const& e) {
       std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
  ```
- File `test_client.cpp`

  ```
   // test_client.cpp
   #include <iostream>

   #include "tcpClient.h"

   // Client side
   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) try {
       // we need 2 things: ip address and port number, in that order
       if (argc != 3) {
           std::cerr << "Usage: ip_address port" << std::endl;
           std::exit(0);
       }
       char* serverIp = argv[1];
       char* port     = argv[2];

       boost::asio::thread_pool ioc(1); // single thread

       TcpClient tcpcli(ioc.get_executor(), serverIp, port);
       tcpcli.StartWriting();

       ioc.join();
   } catch(std::exception const& e) {
       std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
  ```
- File `AppPlugin.cpp`

  ```
   #include "AppPlugin.h"
   #include <ostream>
   #include <sstream>

   #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, TestManagerComInfo const& msg) {
       os << "Request Type: " << static_cast<int>(msg.requestType_) << std::endl;
       os << "Name: " << msg.name_ << std::endl;
       os << "Test Log:" << std::endl;
       for (auto const& [k, v] : msg.testLogType_) {
           os << "  " << k << ": " << v << std::endl;
       }
       os << "Status Type: " << static_cast<int>(msg.statusType_) << std::endl;
       return os;
   }

   template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, TestManagerComInfo& obj, unsigned /*version*/) {
       ar& obj.requestType_& obj.name_& obj.testLogType_& obj.statusType_;
   }

   std::string serializeMessageStruct(TestManagerComInfo& msg) {
       std::ostringstream oss;
       {
           boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(oss);
           archive << msg;
       } // SEHE: completes the archive
       return oss.str();
   }

   TestManagerComInfo DeserializeMessageStruct(std::streambuf& sb) {
       std::istream is(&sb);
       TestManagerComInfo msg;
       boost::archive::text_iarchive(is) >> msg;
       return msg;
   }
  ```
- File `AppPlugin.h`

  ```
   // AppPlugin.h
   #ifndef APPPLUGIN_H
   #define APPPLUGIN_H
   #include <map>
   #include <string>

   enum RequestType {
       kSatelliteStatus     = 0x00,
       kApplicationPresence = 0x01,
       kExecuteTestSuite    = 0x02,
       kTestSuiteLog        = 0x03,
       kTerminate           = 0x04,
   };

   enum StatusType {
       kInit      = 0x00,
       kStarted   = 0x01,
       kCompleted = 0x02,
   };

   enum TestResultType {
       kTestNotExecute,
       kTestPass,
       kTestFail,
       kTestAbort,
   };

   using TestLogType = std::map<std::string, TestResultType>;

   struct TestManagerComInfo {
       RequestType requestType_;
       std::string name_;
       TestLogType testLogType_;
       StatusType  statusType_;

       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, TestManagerComInfo const&);
   };

   /**
    * @fn serializeMessageStruct
    * @brief serialize TestManagerComInfo into string
    * @param msg is the object to serialize
    */
   std::string serializeMessageStruct(TestManagerComInfo& msg);
   TestManagerComInfo DeserializeMessageStruct(std::streambuf& sb);

   #endif // APPPLUGIN_H
  ```

Local demo:

[image]

Comment: I didn't mention everything - like e.g. using `boost::shared_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`. You might want to spend some time comparing the changes on your own pace. As I mentioned, I didn't give the server side a lot of attention.

Comment: For convenience, here's Sources.zip which includes a minimal CMakeLists.txt: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/995b1cc4-e3fa-4065-a13d-8cfcb0d6f9f1/Sources.zip

Comment: HI @sehe, Thanks for your reply. Actually I am making a tcp_communication library for my project, which will provide the API for sending and receiving data over tp from server to client or vice a versa. So I dont want to block anyone thats why want async. I want the communication like this code-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12HzqyoFadKEvJnbY4gU15ZZ0bqrFiduM/view?usp=drivesdk
For building server run -''g++ -o async_server -std=c++14 -pthread tcpserver.cpp -lboost_system'
and for client 'g++ -o async_client -std=c++14 -pthread tcpclient.cpp -lboost_system'.

Comment: In the above shared link after connecting anyone can send data first & other one will get immediately. same functionality I want in my library. if client is sending data server should ready & vice a versa. 
I want to make 4 public API in both side-
StartWriting(std::string), std::string StartReading() in server 
and StartWriting(std::string), std::string StartReading() in client side. This string is my msg which I get from my serialize and deserialize function from AppPlugin.h. The client code which you shared its running in async but now server is not getting hello msg from client.

Comment: Yes it does. I showed you my demo for a reason, with complete code and build instructions. If you don't - there *could* be down to the remark I made _"Hmm. Now I'm noticing the server also uses async_read_some and async_write_some instead of composed operations that avoid partial messages. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader for now."_. You have to understand that TCP stream sockets have no deterministic framing in the transport and you have to provide it at the application level. (In contrast to datagram sockets)